# Pseudo-random numbers generators references

Tags: references, random-generation

I am looking for a good reference to read about pseudorandom number generators. (I do not even know the difference between random and pseudorandom numbers.) Could you please offer some introductory level notes, articles, etc.? (I'd like to add that I've already seen the Wikipedia article).

Comment: What do you want to know about RNGs, specifically?

Comment: What it is :). And how it works. E.g., how such generators are realized in different programming languages (and wheather it depends on the language in reality).